# How can I access the current value of an environment variable in a zsh prexec function?

Tags: zsh

I have a simple function like

```
function clearit() {
  REM=$(($LINENO % $LINES))
  DIV=$(($LINENO / $LINES))
  if [[ $DIV -gt 0 && $REM -lt 3 && $DIV ]]; then
    clear
  fi
  echo $LINENO, $LINES
}
add-zsh-hook preexec clearit
```

In the above function a static value of $LINE and $LINES is added to the prehook function. I want to get the current value when the prexec is executed. How can I do that ?

Comment: It seems that inside a function, `LINENO` gets its value from the line that the particular command is on. Not the user's current LINENO. It's not static since changing `LINES` after creating the hook changes its value. I'm not sure how to get fix it though.

Comment: If you're looking for the current row of the cursor, so you can divide that by total lines in the screen, it is going to be tricky: see this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88296/get-vertical-cursor-position/183121#183121

Answer (score 0):

For normal shell variables, you *will* get the current value:

```
% x=1
% function test_hook() { echo $x; }
% add-zsh-hook preexec test_hook
% true
1
% x=2
1
% true
2
```

However, `$LINENO` is a very special variable. From the documentation:

> LINENO <S>
>
> The line number of the current line within the current script, sourced file, or shell function being executed, whichever was started most recently. Note that in the case of shell functions the line number refers to the function as it appeared in the original definition, not necessarily as displayed by the functions builtin.

When your hook function is executing, it is by definition the most recently started shell function, script or sourced file. So `$LINENO` always gives you the current line *within your hook function*. There is no way to access the `$LINENO` for the outer scope.

However, even if you could access the outer `$LINENO` in your hook, it would lead to very strange behaviour in my opinion. Let's say your terminal is 30 lines high (`$LINES` is 30), it would clear the terminal before executing the 30th, 31st and 32nd command, then nothing for the next 27 commands, then again clearing before the 60th, 61st and 62nd, and so on. I don't think this is remotely what you are trying to achieve...